# Developing a Tor library

Tags: onion-services, development

I want to incorporate Tor in my application in order to access a Tor hidden service. Make GET POST requests to the web server.

Is there any resource I can read to implement a simple Tor client that will allow me to send requests to a webservice ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit, what you mean by Tor library? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JensKubieziel I edited my question

Comment: What is your application? is it code? if so c#, java or something else?

Comment: @puser I am looking for documentation to implement it myself not looging for third party librairies. The application is written in C++

Comment: @ring0 i'd recommend you edit your post to make that more clear.

Comment: are you asking for a way to use the tor source code and connect that way?

Comment: related: https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/7l8k50/is_there_any_cc_library_for_tor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the protocol you should have a look at [the tor specs](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git).

If you understand Java you can also have a look at [orchid](http://www.subgraph.com/orchid.html) or [SilverTunnel-NG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/silvertunnel-ng/) or just have a look at the [tor codebase](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git) itself.

Answer (score 5):

Tor is a socks5 proxy.

[here is the socks5 rfc](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt)

[here is a guide to how socks5 works with tor](http://samsclass.info/122/proj/how-socks5-works.html) read this, it is VERY useful

if using sockets (I assume c++ uses sockets) you will need to

1. connect to tor (127.0.0.1:9050 by default)
2. Send authentication (5,1,0) see rfc part 3
3. Receive the tor response (5,0) see rfc part 3
4. Send Client's Connection request (5,1,0,3 + host length +  a binary representation of the host and port) see rfc part 4
5. receive the tor response (5,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0) see rfc part 6 (there can be a bunch of errors here, so watch out)
6. Send a binary representation of a http request to tor (Tor will forward this to the destination)
7. Receive the http response (will send the header first then the web page)

Comment: Also here is the tor protocol specifications https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt